# filter an observable array by another array?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to pass in an array of ids and filter an observable array for the items that have those  ids what is the best solution?

right now im iterating through the array one by one and filtering an observable array for each individual id.

```
visibleCheckBoxes.each(function (i, v) {
            var item = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.batches(), function (batch) {

                return batch.BatchID() == v.id;
            });

            });
```

Comment: So you want to take all elements in `batches` that have an `id` which is present in `visibleCheckBoxes`?

Comment: yes, thats right. and the ids are guaranteed to be in the batches observable array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will create `filtered` which contains elements from `batches` whose *id* is in `boxes`. It can be greatly simplified by using underscore or something similar.

```
var boxes = ko.observableArray([{id:1},{id:3}]);
var batches = ko.observableArray([{bId:1, name:"ID1"},{bId:2, name:"ID2"},{bId:3, name:"ID3"},{bId:4, name:"ID4"}]);

var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(batches(), function (batch) {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes().length; i++) 
        if (batch.bId == boxes()[i].id) 
            return true;

    return false;
});
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JD2Q2

So in your example it would be something like

```
var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.batches(), function (batch) {
    for (var i = 0; i < visibleCheckBoxes().length; i++)
        if (batch.bId == visibleCheckBoxes()[i].id) 
            return true;

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the id is unique you'd better use [arrayFirst](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html).
*O(n^(n/2))*

```
var batches = self.batches();
visibleCheckBoxes.each(function (i, v) {
    var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(batches , function (batch) {
        return batch.BatchID() == v.id;
    });
});
```

And if you have a lots of item *O(2n)*.

```
batchesDict = {};
var batchesDict = ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.batches(),function(batch){
     batchesDict[batch.BatchID()] = batch;
});

visibleCheckBoxes.each(function (i, v) {
    var item = batchesDict[v.id];
});
```

I hope it helps.